# Passing parameters from Python to a makefile

Tags: python, makefile

As we have a slightly complicated makefile setup I'm using Python as an intermediate step in a series of makefiles to give a setup like this - top level makefile identifies what libraries need to be built and calls a Python script for each one.  The Python does some processing on the options and calls the library makefile.

In the top level we do this:

```
$(LIBS_ALL):
    $(PYTHON) config/buildtools.py $(MAKEFILE) BACON=YES EGGS=YES MUESLI=NO
```

Then ultimately the Python script buildtools.py does this to call gmake with the MAKEFILE:

```
call([path_to_gmake, MAKEFILE, argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], argv[4]])
```

This is paraphrased a little but you get the idea.  I call gmake and pass through the arguments passed in from the top level.  As above, with each argv listed explicitly it works wonderfully, however a slice argv[1:] does not work.  The called gmake behaves like it received no arguments.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because if you slice argv you create a nested list. You should do:

```
call([path_to_gmake, MAKEFILE]+argv[1:5])
```